# Link does not stay open and active

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i have created a navigation that navigates back and forth between sections. I have styled two lists that are supposed to fulfill this task.

1. List: the active link works there as soon as I click a link. The text and the point are unfortunately upside down. When I change the order, the list name / Nav remains in the visible area
2. List: there the point and the name are arranged correctly but the active link cannot be combined somehow.

In both examples, the active link does not remain open. I've been trying it out for a long time and I'm a bit overwhelmed.

```js
$('#menu li a').click(function(){    
    $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');


});
```

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300);


.fa-2x {
font-size: 2em;
}
.fa {
position: relative;
display: table-cell;
width: 60px;
height: 36px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
font-size:20px;
}


.main-menu:hover,nav.main-menu.expanded {
width:250px;
overflow:visible;
}

.main-menu {
background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
border-right:1px solid #e5e5e5;
position:fixed;
top:0;
bottom:0;
height:100%;
right:0;
width:60px;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition:width .05s linear;
transition:width .05s linear;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
z-index:1000;
}

.main-menu>ul {
margin:7px 0;
}

.main-menu li {
position:relative;
display:block;
width:250px;
}

.main-menu li>a {
position:relative;
display:table;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:0;
color:#999;
 font-family: arial;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transform:translateZ(0) scale(1,1);
-webkit-transition:all .1s linear;
transition:all .1s linear;
  
}

.main-menu .nav-icon {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
width:60px;
height:36px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
font-size:18px;
}

.main-menu .nav-text {
position:relative;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
width:190px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.main-menu>ul.logout {
position:absolute;
left:0;
bottom:0;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover {
overflow-y:hidden;
}

.no-touch .scrollable.hover:hover {
overflow-y:auto;
overflow:visible;
}

a:hover,a:focus {
text-decoration:none;
}

nav {
-webkit-user-select:none;
-moz-user-select:none;
-ms-user-select:none;
-o-user-select:none;
user-select:none;
}

nav ul,nav li {
outline:0;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
.main-menu li:hover>a,nav.main-menu li.active>a,.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,.dropdown-menu>.active>a,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,.no-touch .dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li:hover a,.dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li.active a {
color:#fff;
background-color:#999;
}
.area {
float: left;
background: #e2e2e2;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Titillium WebLight'), local('TitilliumWeb-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/titilliumweb/v2/anMUvcNT0H1YN4FII8wpr24bNCNEoFTpS2BTjF6FB5E.woff) format('woff');
}

.active{
background-color:#f30; 
}

section {
    height: 100vh;
    color: rgba(255,255,255, .5);
    font-size: 20vh;
}
section:nth-child(odd) {
    background: blue
}
section:nth-child(even) {
    background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
 
  </head>
  <body>
 
  
  <div id="nav" class="area"></div><nav class="main-menu">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#slide01" style="text-align:right">
                        <i class="fa fa fa-circle fa-2x"></i>                    
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Nav 1
                        </span>
                    </a>
                  
                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#slide02" style="text-align:right">
                        <i class="fa fa fa-circle fa-2x"></i>                    
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Nav 2
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    
                </li>
                <li class="has-subnav">
                    <a href="#slide03" style="text-align:right">
                        <i class="fa fa fa-circle fa-2x"></i>                                            
                        <span class="nav-text">
                            Nav 3
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    
              
            </ul>

        </nav>
        
        <section id="slide01">Section 1</section>
<section id="slide02">Section 2 </section>
<section id="slide03">Section 3</section>
        
        
  </body>
    </html>
```

```css
h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3em !important;
}
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    padding: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #555;
}
.list-group-item {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
    border: none !important;
    font-size: 2em;
}
.list-group-item a, .list-group-item a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.inner {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.inner a, .inner a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Consolas, "Andale Mono", "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Courier New", "monospace";
}
section {
    height: 100vh;
    color: rgba(255,255,255, .5);
    font-size: 20vh;
}
section:nth-child(odd) {
    background: blue
}
section:nth-child(even) {
    background: red
}
.test {
    padding: 0 15px !important;
}
.test:hover .later {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
}
.test:hover .before {
    display: none;
}
.test .later {
    display: none;
    z-index: 100;
}
.test .before {
    display: block;
    z-index: 50;
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section id="slide01">Section 1</section>
<section id="slide02">Section 2 </section>
<section id="slide03">Section 3</section>
<section id="slide04">Section 4</section>
<section id="slide05">Section 5</section>
<nav id="nav">
<div class="inner">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#slide01">
      <div class="test"><span class="before"> •</span><span class="later">Nav 1 •</span></a></div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#slide02">
      <div class="test"><span class="before"> •</span><span class="later">Nav 2 •</span></a></div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#slide03">
      <div class="test"><span class="before"> •</span><span class="later">Nav 3 •</span></a></div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#slide04">
      <div class="test"><span class="before"> •</span><span class="later">Nav 4 •</span></a></div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#slide05">
      <div class="test"><span class="before"> •</span><span class="later">Nav 5 •</span></a></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

[image] -> Active status

Answer (score 0):

The second example does not have an element with ID "menu," so your JavaScript isn't targeting anything.  For the second example specifically:

Change your jQuery to

```
 $('.list-group-item').click(function(){    
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

This will properly apply the "active" class to your list-group-item when clicked.

However, the other issue is that ".active" won't do anything right now because you are overriding Bootstrap's built-in styles with this rule:

```
.list-group-item {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0) !important;
    border: none !important;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

The **!important** on background-color is keeping the color the same even when ".active" is applied.

Instead of using !important, you could increase the specificity of your rule by writing it like so:

```
.list-group .list-group-item {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: none !important;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

However I'm not sure what you mean by "In both examples, the active link does not remain open."  Your ".active" class currently only applies a background color to the active link (both in the way you've written it in example 1 and the way Bootstrap styles it in example 2) and this is what we fixed with the code above.  If you want more styling applied to the active link, it will need to be added.

Comment: Thanks for the great tips :).
I was able to apply this to the 2nd example. Active means that the writing Nav 1, for example, remains. Currently, the NAV only open when hovering and do not remain actively open. I got it with .test: active .later {
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    color: #fff;
} tries. But unfortunately it doesn't work.